# Database entry different from outputted data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a piece of code that is supposed to count the records based on a service ID in my database.
This works fine, and outputs fine.

However, when I try to store that counted data (The exact same variables that I display properly), the numbers are getting all messed up.

```
    foreach($sids as $sid) {

    $csv = array($date, $sid);
    $count = $bdb->GetOne("
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM User_Services as us
    INNER JOIN Cust_Info as ci on ci.CustID=us.CustID
    INNER JOIN Services as s on s.ServiceID=us.ServiceID
    WHERE s.ServiceID=? 
    AND ci.Active=1
    ", array($sid));

    $csv[] = $count;

    $bdb->Execute("
        INSERT INTO service_count_snapshot
        VALUES (?,?,?)
    ", array($date, $sid, $count));
    }
```

I have about 400 Service IDs, and after it gets to 127, it is always entering the Service ID as 127. However, the count of records is entered properly each time.

[Here is what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6iuy.jpg)

My question is, is this a coding issue? Am I processing the data incorrectly? Is it possibly a visual bug, and the data is actually correct? How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like the data type is incorrect, make sure it's an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your `id` field is of the wrong type. Maybe it is just `TINYINT` - check back that it is of type `INT(10)` and with `UNSIGNED` attribute.

Comment: Can tinyint only go up to 127?

Comment: A signed tinyint can only hold 1 byte of information, which is 256 different numbers. Since it is signed, it holds from -128 to 127

Comment: Works perfectly when I change it to int. I didnt know that that could even be an issue. Thanks